# Have you used a core drill on a foundation wall?

Tags: concrete, foundation, venting

I'm looking to use a 4" core drill on a poured concrete foundation wall. The hole will be about 2" or so down from the top of the wall. The rental place has a handheld core drill with a water attachment. Does anyone have experience with this? Also any tips or best practices that you could share?

Comment: "*Have you used a core drill on a foundation wall?*"  NO, no i have not.  Did you ask the rental place if the tool is the right one for what you want to use it for? Have you looked up the model of the drill you want use, **done any research** as to how it is used and for what applications it is intended to be used for? There are YouTube video tutorials for almost any tool, or similar tools,

Comment: You will have a problem if you hit a steel rebar.

Comment: Yes, absolutely! Read The Fine Manual. Seriously, ask the rental place for the model number and manual if they have a spare; if not then find a manual online. Read it from cover-to-cover and you should be all set.

Answer (score 2):

I have used several different core drills. For horizontal drilling I have anchored the machine one I used expanding sleeve anchors others are held in place by hand and that one can be like a torture device these drills are slow and make a mess if inside.  Keeping constant pressure on the cutter will allow the cutters to do there job.
For the mess I found making a plastic sheet taped to the wall to direct the water into a bucket and pump it out to be the best method inside to control the mess.

I have had to split the slug of concrete once when the forms may have blown and the wall was thicker but breaking the slug allowed the cutter to go in further and finish the cut.